# Access Denied during Ajax call in IE

Tags: ajax

I have a VF page which makes a Ajax call to an external REST API.
It works perfectly as expected in Chrome browser, but it fails in IE with a error "Access Denied".

Initially, IE gave a error "No Transport", after which I added a parameter before the Ajax call like `"$support.cors = true;"`

Not sure what the issue is and why the call is not working in IE.

Any inputs would be very helpful.

Here is Ajax Call:

```
 $.support.cors = true; 
$.ajax
       (
        {
            url : webLink,
            type : 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function (request)
            {
                request.setRequestHeader("Name", "value");
            },
            crossDomain: true,
            success : function(result)
            {
            }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Is The REST API external or is Force Rest API ?

If you are trying to ajax Salesforce in a VF Page you should use [Ajax Toolkit](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/ajax/). e.g:

```
<apex:page >
    <script >var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}'; </script>
    <script src="../../soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">window.onload = setupPage;
    function setupPage() {
      var state = { 
          output : document.getElementById("output"),
          startTime : new Date().getTime()};
      var callback = {
          onSuccess: layoutResults,
          onFailure: queryFailed,
          source: state};
      sforce.connection.query(
          "Select Id, Name, Industry From Account order by Industry",
           callback);
  } ....
```

If you are trying to ajax an External (cross domain) Rest API you should use [Remote Ajax Call](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Ajax_Proxy) e.g:

```
sforce.connection.remoteFunction({
        url : "http://services.xmethods.net/soap",
        requestData: envelope,
        method: "POST",
        onSuccess : function(response) {
            document.getElementById("result").value = response.textContent;
        },
        onFailure : function(response) {
             document.getElementById("result").value = "Failed  " + response;
        }
    });
```

You should add `services.xmethods.net` to Remote Sites Settings as Daniel commented.

In addition, If you are looking to hit an external API from the browser(bypassing the SF Proxy) you should try [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). I think it is by default supported for most of modern browsers. 
However, your API should be JSONP compatible, by just wrapping the json response using callback parameter.

e.g:

- request :  `externalAPI/method?callback=63687345687346 //this parameter is set by the browser`
- response:  `63687345687346({result:ok})`

Finally, if you need to get data bypassing the SF Proxy using cors or jsonp  maybe the proper forum should be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript

Comment: Awesome answer, I have not discovered the remoteFunction in the ajax toolkit. For this to work will the `services.xmethods.net` domain need to be added to the Remote Site Settings?

Comment: Hi Martin, Thanks for the reply, the whole purpose of me using the Ajax to call a external REST API is to avoid the server interaction from my page. I want the call to be done on browser side. using a RemoteFunction will be a hit to the server. Correct me if my assumption is correct.

Comment: Prashant - I updated your question to specify an external REST API, I think most Salesforce.com developers would assume you meant the Salesforce REST API without that clarification!

Comment: Thanks Daniel to notice that. @PrashantKaradi: I've updated my answer adding a new approach.

Comment: Thanks Martin for the reply! I have to use XDomainRequest for IE. But XDR do not allow us to pass custom headers and the REST API which I am invoking requires a header to be passed. :(